# Why does using 'if' in python give me syntax error results when all of my syntaxes are right?

Tags: python, if-statement

I write a code with if and else in python ....
everything is OK but give me syntax error
I don't know why!
my code:

```
if codepersoneli==123:
    username=input('please enter your username: ')
    password=int(input('please enter your password: ')
    if (username == 'mkj') and (password==251):
        print('welcome Mr.john')
    else:
        print('wrong username or password')
elif (codepersoneli==456):
    username=input('please enter your username: ')
    password=int(input('please enter your password: '))
    if(username=='msy') and (password==456):
        print('welcome Jain')
    else:
        print('wrong username or password')
elif (codepersoneli==789):
    username=input('please enter your username: ')
    password=int(input('please enter your password'))
    if(username=='mry') and (password==987):
        print('welcome David')
    else:
        print('wrong username or password')
else:
    print('wrong personal code')
```

when I run this code in VScode give me : line 5
if (username == 'mkj') and (password==251):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please extend your question to include the actual error message? Thank you.

Comment: If you have an error then it's important to show us the actual error (including traceback). Usually the error will be exactly where it's telling you it is or in the preceding couple of lines.

Comment: when I run this code in VScode give me : line 5
    if (username == 'mkj') and (password==251):
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis in line 3. You wrote this: `password=int(input('please enter your password: ')`. Please check your code thoroughly.

```
password=int(input('please enter your password: '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you got that error because you forgot to write an extra `)` in the line 3 in the `int` statement, the code should looks like the following.

```
if codepersoneli==123:
    username=input('please enter your username: ')
    password=int(input('please enter your password: '))
    if (username == 'mkj') and (password==251):
        print('welcome Mr.john')
    else:
        print('wrong username or password')
elif (codepersoneli==456):
    username=input('please enter your username: ')
    password=int(input('please enter your password: '))
    if(username=='msy') and (password==456):
        print('welcome Jain')
    else:
        print('wrong username or password')
elif (codepersoneli==789):
    username=input('please enter your username: ')
    password=int(input('please enter your password'))
    if(username=='mry') and (password==987):
        print('welcome David')
    else:
        print('wrong username or password')
else:
    print('wrong personal code')
```

I hope it may help you!

Answer (score 0):

You missed the ending parenthesis in this line- `password=int(input('please enter your password: ')`

It should be-

```
password=int(input('please enter your password: '))
```

Hope it helped!